# Keep calm and help me find Jeff's password!

Tags: riddle, cipher, rhyme

My friend Jeff just went away on a one-year world tour. Unfortunately, he's got my important research on his computer. Of course, it is locked by password. I tried to get a hold of him, but I can't reach him on his phone. He might already be on the top of Himalaya...

So I went to his house, searched his office for any Post-it note or other clue he might have left and finally stumbled on a piece of paper with his writing. Can you help me decipher it and find his password?

---

The content of his note is as follows :

> I'm known throughout the world
> Even though I'm no more the tallest
> I'm starting to get old
> But one day per year, I'm still on my brightest
>
> My half-sister lives in a far away country
> Near the ocean, while I'm stuck in the city
> I could be called an iron lady
> But please don't, this one's historically my enemy
>
> **"The answer is the key, in more sense than one?"**
>
> *036064313-115102518* : MIRYLPXWCLKIMSYLNAWHHFJUJSHPESEIM
> *048512988+002174020* : NMXZMDVSMYZZQJSXLOOJXTIYZJNPICOWVHM
> *035393091+139444354* : MKMNRZTHKARXIXMMHTYEQRWC

Hint 1 :

> The answers to the ciphers are to be taken in their own languages

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to the riddle (not the cipher):

> Eiffel Tower

I'm known throughout the world

> obvious

Even though I'm no more the tallest

> For four decades it was the world’s tallest structure but there are lots of taller buildings now

I'm starting to get old

> Sad but true.

But one day per year, I'm still on my brightest

> [image]
> Christmas...

My half-sister lives in a far away country

> Statue of Liberty was also built by Eiffel (half-sister sharing a father)

Near the ocean, while I'm stuck in the city

> is placed pretty near the ocean (on an island).

I could be called an iron lady

> That's how the Eiffel Tower is called

But please don't, this one's historically my enemy

> Hm.. Some historical facts certainly mention that.

**"The answer is the key, in more sense than one?"**
As Rubio pointed out:

> the numeric strings are geo coordinates:

036064490-115101990 is

> Eiffel Tower Restaurant in Las Vegas

048512988+002174020 is

> Eiffel Tower (Paris)

035391859+139442639 is

> Tokyo Tower - Tokyo, Japan

So the first sense of *the answer* being a key is

> all the locations present some kind of Eiffel Tower.

The second sense is the key to the cipher below as @Ivanhoe commented:

> which is Vigenere's cipher with key "EIFFELTOWER"

I am sorry for wrong deciphering - I had some letters mixed up (switched 'p' and 'q' don't ask me why) - now it should be correct (thanks to @Ivanhoe again).

MIRYLPXWCLKIMSYLNAWHHFJUJSHPESEIM

> It is from Vegas, so the language is english.
>  iamtheeighteenthchildofmendeleiev (in english he is spelled Mendeleev, right?)
>  Riddle:
> **I am the eighteenth child of Mendeleiev**
>  Answer:
> **Argon (Ar)** (18th element in Mendeleiev's periodic table)

NMXZMDVSMYZZQJSXLOOJXTIYZJNPICOWVHM

> This is from Paris, so the language is french
>  jesuiscequivientavantcequejepossede
>  **Je suis ce quivient avant ce que je possede**
>  Riddle:
>  **I am what comes before what I have.**
>  Answer:
>  **my**, as it comes before i.e. "**my** car". In french that would be **ma**, **mon** or **mes**.

MKMNRZTHKARXIXMMHTYEQRWC

> This is from Tokyo, so the language is japanese
> ichinoatowatashiwakimasu
>  **Ichi no ato watashi wa kimasu**
>  Riddle:
>  **I come after one**
>  Answer:
>  **two** which in japanese spells **ni**

The deciphered parts together make

> **Armani**, **Armonni** or **Armesni**
>  So the password is likely to be: **Armani** as it is the only proper word from the three (Giorgio Armani is the founder of a famous Italian fashion house).

Comment: How is Italy "far-away" from France considering they border one another?

Comment: Well, you're right, that is not the furthest of countries :P I'll try to fix it.

Comment: @oleslaw You've got the riddle part absolutely right! +1

Comment: You're almost right, but it seems like you've got some errors in your Vigenere deciphering. Which is why it looks like there is some mispelling in the english, french and japanese sentences. (I used websites to encrypt/decrypt)

Comment: Also, you've got the first part (in english) right.

Comment: The French sentence is "JESUISCEQUIVIENTAVANTCEQUEJEPOSSEDE" which translates to "I AM WHAT COMES BEFORE WHAT I HAVE".

Comment: corrected the transaltions. I'm sorry for so many mistakes.

Comment: Foreign languages sentences are right. For the japanese one, you're almost there, you just need one more step!

Comment: I wonder if you could take the Japanese riddle even *more* literally and have it be just the letter N. If the French clue could be something that equates to Oxygen, then the password could be "atmosphere" because you would have nitrogen, oxygen, and argon. My train of thought is probably on the wrong track, though.

Comment: My other thought is if you take the French riddle the same way as the Japanse so you would take what comes before "what I have" in the French which I think would be either avant or ce (I don't know French grammar.) That combines into `arceno` which means... nothing?

Comment: @EngineerToast The japanese riddle's answer is indeed "two", translated in japanese as per the hint. As for the french riddle, it's quite not that litteral...

Comment: @oleslaw Your answer, while acceptable, is not exactly the one I intended. In french "my" can be translated in two ways (according to gender) and I expected the other one, giving a different word. As soon as you change your answer accordingly, I'll accept it. Good job!

Comment: @Thrax I believe there are 3 forms of "my" in french and no other than already used actually form a word with the japanese and english parts together.

Comment: @oleslaw You're right, I was going for "mon" to get the word "ar-mon-mi" (Harmony). Well done.

Answer (score 2):

A couple UPDATED additional comments here -

> the numeric strings are geo coordinates:
>
>  048512988+002174020 : Eiffel Tower
>  036064490-115101990 : Eiffel Tower Restaurant in Las Vegas
>  035391859+139442639 : Tokyo Tower - Tokyo, Japan

As for the cipher text - from the clues I assumed this would be

> an Eiffel Code (Caesar cipher with shift of 6)

but it seems not to be. So now I am at a loss on how to proceed.

Comment: You found a clue. I actually mistyped 2 of the 3 numbers (see edit of questions). While that should change the places you found out, it's not critical to solve the cipher. +1

Comment: The second place is not exactly the one i'm referring to (while it's actually quite one and only 2D spot)

Comment: 036064490-115101990 seems correct, i think.  Eiffel Tower Restaurant in Las Vegas.

Comment: Well that's what I was trying to point to, but I'm no expert of manipulating GPS coordinates. I was using this notation : "Latitude: 36° 06' 43.13" N / Longitude: -115° 10' 25.18" W" and stripping anything else than signs and numbers.

Comment: yup. i figured that out.  google maps gives the coords I gave as being at the restaurant, which I finally noticed was roughly across the street from the Fountains of Bellagio location you'd given.  I assumed that had to be it. :)

Comment: The strings are actually Vigenere encoded with the key being EIFFELTOWER. They yield 3 sentences, each in a different language(French, English and Japanese). There was no point going for an answer myself as the puzzle was half-way solved already.

Comment: @Ivanhoe The final answer has still not been given, so you can post a partial answer with the last part.

Comment: Well done @Ivanhoe...  Now check that humility and put the answer down!

Comment: @Ivanhoe I tried the vigenere hundred times - I did not get the sentences because I shifted by 1 too many chars -.-

Comment: @oleslaw I used the Vigenère square from wikipedia. Worked fine. I like learning about old encryption techniques like this. They're so simple, yet effective.

Comment: @n00dles For some reason I used a=1... That's why I failed.